# MongoDB Morphia save() generates two objects with the same ID

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo, morphia, nosql

I have a java application that connects to a MongoDB Database through the Morphia library. My POJO that I store in the database has String field named _id and annotated with the @Id annotation (com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Id;).

I'm generating a new object ( it has null _id). 
I call save(object) on the datastore provided by morphia.
The object gets updated after being stored and now has an _id value.
I call save(object) again and a new entry is created in the database with the same _id.
All consecutive save() operations on the object overwrite the old one and do not produce any new entries in the database.

So for example, after 10 save() calls on the same object my database ends up looking like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "539ade7ee4b0451f28ba0e2e"} , "className" : "blabla" , blabla ...}
{ "_id" : "539ade7ee4b0451f28ba0e2e" , "className" : "blabla" , blabla ...}
```

As seen those two entries have the same _id but with different representation. One has it as an object the other as a string. Normally I should have only one entry shouldn't I ?

Comment: That's really strange. The index on `_id` is supposed to have an unique-constraint. It shouldn't be possible for two documents with the same `_id` to exist in the same collections.

Comment: @Philipp : {"$oid" : "539ade7ee4b0451f28ba0e2e"} isn't the same as "539ade7ee4b0451f28ba0e2e" and will not violate the unique constraint

Comment: @John : Can you show us your code. This is almost certainly an issue with your code.

Comment: @RemonvanVliet OK, I missed that.

Comment: @Philipp No worries, it wasn't very well formatted but I see you fixed that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a string for the `_id`. This will fix your problem:

```
@Id
protected ObjectId id;
```

While you could use `protected String id` (this shouldn't create duplicates IMHO), you'll have problems if you use `@Reference` and might run into weird edge cases elsewhere, so avoid it if possible.

Comment: This worked. I was using @Id public String id; I wonder though why isn't the id allowed to be a string once annotated correctly.

Comment: Datatypes are mapped by Morphia. Long ago ``@Id`` has been a string but they've changed it. I'd assume to ensure the right constraint for the ObjectId data type. For details, check the mailinglist on Google somewhere around 2010/2011

Comment: You can use a String for your ID but you have to provide that value.   The java driver will generate an _id before it inserts the document but it will generate that value using ObjectID.  Since your object uses a String for its ID, that ObjectID value gets converted to a String before being set back on your entity.